# Batch PnP PowerShell command in a recursive function

Tags: powershell, recursion, sharepoint-online, batching

Currently in the nightly version of PnP.PowerShell, we can batch multiple PnP requests(mentioned below).

```
$batch = New-PnPBatch

1..100 | ForEach-Object{ Add-PnPListItem -List "ItemTest" -Values @{"Title"="Test Item Batched $_"} -Batch $batch }
Invoke-PnPBatch -Batch $batch
```

But if I need to batch the command from a recursive function how we can perform that?
My requirement is to get Folders and Sub Folders in a Document Library. The code is given below.

```
Function GetFolders($folderUrl)
{
    $folderColl=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderUrl -ItemType Folder
    # Loop through the folders
    foreach($folder in $folderColl)
    {
        $newFolderURL= $folderUrl+"/"+$folder.Name
        Write-Host $folder.Name " - " $newFolderURL
        GetFolders($newFolderURL)
    }
}

GetFolders($FolderPath)
```

How I can make the above code to use Batching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/batching.html

`Get-PnPFolderItem` cmd doesnot support batching.

[image]

Comment: The current version of PNP supports only the below commands for batching. Get-PnPFolderItem command doesn't support it.


Add-PnPListItem, Set-PnPListItem, Remove-PnPListItem, Publish-PnPSyntexModel, Unpublish-PnPSyntexModel, Request-PnPSyntexClassifyAndExtract